# Modifying Transfer Rates in Powershell

Tags: powershell, networking, copy, robocopy

Is there a way to modify a transfer rate when running a PowerShell script?

The reason I'm asking is that I have to copy over a hundred files ranging from 200 KB to just under a Meg.  The problem is that these files reside in another location within our WAN and our connection is rather slow.  If I try to copy these files during business hours, it kills the connection and services that are tied back to the central office die.

I looked at the performance monitor and saw how the file transfers from the server jumped pretty high, so I thought if there's a way to throttle the file copy speed, then I might be able to copy the files during production hours without effecting the network connectivity.

Comment: It's hard to comment on your issue without seeing your code. But it sounds like you are using `robocopy.exe` to do the copy which has a parameter for interpacket gap `/IPG` which you can modify to add time between when packets are sent to reduce bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the bandwidth usage when you copy files with robocopy you can use the following syntax:

To copy a directory using **/IPG** to limit bandwidth usage. General thumb rule is to use **/IPG:750** which will use roughly *1Mbps*.

```
Robocopy /ipg:750 /z /r:3 /w:3 /tee /LOG+:c:\robolog.txt \\server01\share \\server02\share
```

More details on this context are present [Robocopy Usage Details](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx?tduid=(dd7d97730b0d68fa7483e41e83dd4f27)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-FANdk2kkVD8ye2uA11P1hg)())

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

powershell has the start-sleep cmdlet to introduce a delay between operations.

if you are running your file copy routine in a loop from a listing of files (perhaps from a directory listing result), you could place a start-sleep between each file copy to free up the network for other actions.

as far as doing the same inside the actual file copy routine, you'd have to write your own file copy script using .NET objects.  For example, you could open a FileStream object against the source file, then pull 4k of data into a buffer, then sleep, and repeat.  when you have pulled all the data, you can save it to a new file.